# How to run a bash one liner within nvim

Tags: neovim, bash

I am running the latest version of nvim on the latest version of  arch.

I have this bash one liner which works as intended

```
echo; lpstat -p | sed 's/printer //g' | sed 's/is idle.  enabled since.*//g'; echo"
```

I wish to assign the above command to a keyboard shortcut within nvim and run it within nvim so that it drops the result within the currently open nvim text file

Here is what I have in .vimrc

```
nnoremap <leader><leader>p :!echo; lpstat -p | sed 's/printer //g' | sed 's/is idle.  enabled since.*//g'; echo
```

but it does not work

How do I wrap the bash command up so it is treated as a one liner then get it to drop the result into the open text file at the cursor?

Comment: Well, first look at `:h :r!`.

Comment: thanks for that I think I have forgotten how to interpret the manual. I have `nnoremap <leader><leader>p :r!{echo; lpstat -p | sed 's/printer //g' | sed 's/is idle.  enabled since.*//g'; echo}` but that does not work

Comment: "Does not work" doesn't help me much. Why don't you start with just part of your shell command and build it up a bit at a time until you find what's causing problems. Because the basic form of `:nnoremap XX :r!shell-cmd` is valid.

Comment: thanks. Brackets gone. Error is `E492: Not an editor command:  sed 's/printer //g' | sed 's/is idle.  enabled since.*//g'; echo`. Think it is looking at `|` and wants `<bar>` so may be is seeing it as a vim vcommand and not bash.

Comment: Try escaping the pipes... `\|`.

Comment: Thanks escaping the `|` with `\|` did it.

Comment: @Kes please post an answer if you have solved your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution. What I needed to do was

1. insert an `r` to read the result of the bash one liner into the current file, and
2. escape the two occurances of `|` with `\|`

```
" below gets current list of printers  
nnoremap <leader><leader>p :r !echo; lpstat -p \| sed 's/printer //g' \| sed 's/is idle.  enabled since.*//g'; echo<cr>
```

Comment: Another approach could be to use your shell to define an alias for that whole lpstat command, and then your nnoremap command wouldn't need to escape as many characters.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might be some escaping or white space problem so initially set-up an `alias printer_list="command here"` within `.bash_aliases` but for some reason it did not work. Probarly something to do with my config. I beleive it should have worked. But I got it working within `.vimrc` anyways. Thanks.